# How to transform an asynchronous function into a synchronous function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have an async function

```
const thirdPartyFoo = async () => { ... }
```

What I want to do is transform this function into a synchronous function, so when I call it, it awaits to be resolved to continue.

I can't use `async`/`await` or `.then` because here is my case.

I have a function `foo` that uses the `thirdPartyFoo` and it's called by other places in the application. I can't use `.then` because I need to return a value from `thirdPartyFoo`, but it can't be a promise.

```
function foo(){
    // some code

    thirdPartyFoo()

    // some code

   return bar // this can't be a Promise
}
```

What I need is something similar to the ajax `async: false` behavior.

How can I achieve this behavior giving any `async` function?

Comment: In a nutshell: you can't. End of story. If `foo` calls an async function, it itself must be async, and anything that calls it must be too. Turtles all the way down.

Comment: `return Promise.reject("sad promise noises")`

Comment: `.then(you => need.to('find', a => way['to']('deal')).with('it'))`

Comment: @deceze if I can't, how does `async: false` of the `ajax` do it? Going to make a question about it